# opencv python not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to do a gesture controlled smart mirror. But then when I try to run the `test.py`, the camera was on for one second, and then suddenly closed. This is the output that I got.

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: SelectSelector
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "test.py", line 85, in ManageMotion
    gesture = motion.GetGesture()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SmartMirror\Motion\motion.py", line 192, in GetGesture
    self.TryToTrackHand()
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SmartMirror\Motion\motion.py", line 116, in TryToTrackHand
    foundPalm = search_hand.SearchPalmFromMask(search_hand_mask)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SmartMirror\Motion\gesture.py", line 134, in SearchPalmFromMask
    if self.InitFromMask(search_hand_mask):
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SmartMirror\Motion\gesture.py", line 101, in InitFromMask
    (_, contours, _) = cv2.findContours(search_hand_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

[ WARN:0] global D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-4.1.2\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.findContours()` function will return 2 values, not 3.

Read them as:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(...)
```